# При формировании формы ajax, на самбмите нет переменной

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, form, javascript

Есть некая форма. В ней 3 зависимых селекта. При выборе последнего, формируется формируется массив текстовых инпутов feature[*]. (

```
<input type="text" name="feature[]" value=""
```

)

При сабмите формы, во входящем посте переменной feature нет.

Есть ли нюанс какой нибудь в ХТМЛ, что пришедшая часть формы аяксом потом не будет видна между тегами <form></form?>

Пришедший из ajax html вывожу на страницу $('#features_list').html(data);

UPD. Прописал для формы id="item-edit" и для каждого возвращаемого инпута form="item-edit" и заработало.

Comment: Нажмите ответить на свой вопрос и в тему добавьте [решено]

Answer (score 1):

> При сабмите формы, во входящем посте переменной feature нет.

Для начала надо проверить есть ли небходимые данные данные на посте на клиенте, если да то они просто не биндятся на сервере

> Есть ли нюанс какой нибудь в ХТМЛ, что пришедшая часть формы аяксом потом не будет видна между тегами <form></form?>

кажись таких ограничений нету, и постится будет все что имеет атрбут name внутри формы